# Permutations and Combinations based probblem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Find the value of the expression:

$$
1+1\times1!+2\times2!+3\times3!+.....+n\times n!
$$

It is a problem based on the concept of permutations and combinations I don't have a perfect idea to solve this. As I use a very long method which is worthless. Suggest me some easier as well as shorter method. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for a closed-form expression?

Comment: Yes sir more like a short expression let me give you the options.

Comment: Must in involve combinatorics?

Comment: The options are a.n!     b.(n-1)!    c.(n+1)!    d.n*(n+1)!

Comment: @RajagopalanGangadharan: what about putting $n=3$ and cross the only possible option, then?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I did the same you have suggested but then that's the very long method i mentioned at the top.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a combinatorial argument. We’ll count the permutations of $[n+1]=\{1,\ldots,n+1\}$ that are not the identity permutation $123\ldots n(n+1)$ in two ways. There are clearly $(n+1)!-1$ such permutations.

For each such permutation $\pi=p_1p_2\ldots p_{n+1}$ let $m(\pi)=\max\{k:p_{k+1}\ne k+1\}$; $m(\pi)$ exists, since $\pi$ is not the identity permutation. Note that $m(\pi)\ge 1$: if $p_1\ne 1$, then necessarily there is some $k>1$ such that $p_k\ne k$. For $k=1,\ldots,n$ let $P_k$ be the set of non-identity permutations $\pi$ of $[n+1]$ such that $m(\pi)=k$; clearly

$$(n+1)!-1=\sum_{k=1}^n|P_k|\;.$$

For all $\pi\in P_k$ we have $p_{k+1}\ne k+1$ and $p_i=i$ for $k+1<i\le n+1$, so $p_1p_2\ldots p_{k+1}$ is a permutation of $[k+1]$. The only restriction is that $p_{k+1}\ne k+1$, so it can be any permutation of $[k+1]$ that does not have $k+1$ as a fixed point. There are therefore $k$ possible values for $p_{k+1}$, and the remaining $k$ members of $[k+1]$ can be permuted arbitrarily, so there are altogether $k\cdot k!$ such permutations, and $|P_k|=k\cdot k!$. Thus,

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot k!=\sum_{k=1}^n|P_k|=(n+1)!-1\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^n i\times i! + \sum_{i = 0}^n i! = \sum_{i=1}^n(i+1)!
$$
so
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^n i\times i! = (n+1)! - 1,
$$
so your expression is precisely $(n+1)!$.

Comment: Thank you so much but can you suggest me of some method that proceeds by using combinatorics .